# Insert line breaks into an IRC message

Tags: line-breaks, irc

I'm trying to programmatically send IRC messages with the `PRIVMSG` command. IRC uses `CRLF` to delimit separate commands, so "enter" is the end of each command.

I want to send a single message with line breaks in it so that the recipient (a human IRC user) sees a response with breaks. Is this possible? Can I use some other line break character? Should I just split the message at linebreaks and send them as multiple messages?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IRC protocol does not allow CR and/or LF in its message, except for CRLF at the end.  See [RFC 1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-2.3.1) for detail.

Comment: So the only way to send a true multiline message is by using CRLF?

Comment: I think it is not possible. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459#section-8
`recognition that any LF or CR anywhere in a message marks the end of that message (instead of requiring CR-LF);`

Comment: IRC v3 includes [multiline message](https://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/multiline) as far as August 2021 it is still a work-in-progress specification.